# Aurelia change.delegate/trigger not working in Firefox if checked and disabled bound to same value

Tags: aurelia

I have a question regarding the change.delegate/trigger in Aurelia with a checkbox input. I noticed that if you have a checkbox and you bind the disabled and checked attributes to the same value, the change event is never fired in Firefox, but in every other browser.

I had a little talk over at the gitter for Aurelia and I was advised to ask this as a SO question so others can see it and maybe someone from the Aurelia team can comment on this if this is expected behavior? It may just be some Firefox related thing and has nothing to do with Aurelia.

You can test this yourself at https://gist.run/?id=092b50d9fe3fefa354c73a210de9489f

Comment: as a compromise, you can bypass the browser issue by using BindingEngine to manually listen to state change instead of binding to change event on UI. But this doesn't tell you who changed it. https://gist.run/?id=7e5cc6f24def61c364460ff312247cea